# mysqli and passing a query as parameter - no results

Tags: php, mysqli

This is my code:

```
$sql = $_POST['sql'];
....
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
```

This does not return any results. So i echoed the $sql variable and this is the result:

```
SELECT o.entity_id, o.increment_id FROM sales_flat_order o JOIN sales_flat_order_payment p ON o.entity_id = p.parent_id JOIN sales_flat_order_address a ON o.entity_id = a.parent_id WHERE a.country_id = \'DE\' ORDER BY o.entity_id DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Now, when I assign this to the $sql variable directly, it works. What could be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: The ``\`` in that query are likely producing a syntax error. Why are those quotes escaped? Did you check for SQL error messages? Do you have magic quotes on? Why are you accepting arbitrary queries from users in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Well, first you could test `$result` and output the last error with `$mysqli->error` when it's false, that would give you details on what's wrong.

Secondly, you should NOT execute a query that's coming from POST or GET parameter, that's how you allow anyone to do anything on your database with sql injection. That's a big security breach.

Thirdly, the issue is probably on POST encoding (note the quotes `\'DE\'`) so if you `urldecode` and/or `stripslashes` your `$sql` it would probably work